# Accessing ICommands from MainWindow : Josh Smith's Article

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, mainwindow

I am following [Josh Smith's Design explaining WPF + MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). I almost have the same requirement as his demo application. I have to assign the Save command from his CustomerViewModel class to a Toolbar button in the Main Window.

Is it possible to do through XAML or only through code-behind and how?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
<Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289" >
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="Save"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I am pretty sure this calls the default save method, but if you want to define a custom save method you could do:

```
<Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289" >
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding Path="CustomSaveCommand"}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Make sure you add a datacontext reference to your viewmodel like this

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <my:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Yes but this will call Main Window's CustomSaveCommand. I want to call CustomerViewModel's CustomSaveCommand.

Comment: Then simply change your DataContext to whatever you would like it to be. This is just an example and will not necessarily apply 100% to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, Paul. Here's what I ended up doing. 
As I mentioned above, I was using Josh Smith's design, I wanted to call the `Save()` method (Command) of `CustomerViewModel` object from the MainWindowViewModel. 
So from the Main window I attached a click event to my Toolbar Button like this.

```
<Button Name="btnSaveAllWorkspaces" ToolTip="Save All Open Workspaces" Content="Save All" Click="OnSaveAllWorkspacesClicked"/>
```

And then in code behind,

```
private void OnSaveAllWorkspacesClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainVM != null)
        {
            if (MainVM.Workspaces != null && MainVM.Workspaces.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (WorkspaceViewModel wkVM in MainVM.Workspaces)
                {
                    CustomerViewModel vm = wkVM as CustomerViewModel;
                    if (vm != null)
                        vm.Save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Initially I just wanted to save the currently active Workspace only, but then I thought as it is a Global Button on top of all the Workspaces, it makes sense to save all the open workspaces, hence the `foreach` loop.

Please free feel to share if there is a better way to do this just through XAML?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I knew whatever I had done earlier was a workaround and it was dirty. As I understood more about MVVM, I kept re-factoring the code. Here's what I did.

Added the ICommand Proerty for SaveCommand on MainWindowViewModel, and bound it to the toolbutton on Main Window. It just delegates the call to the currently active WorksSpaceViewModel's SaveCommand.

```
   public override ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentWorkspace != null ? _currentWorkspace.SaveCommand : new RelayCommand ( null, param => false);
        }
    }
```

and as in the original code, where it keeps track of current workspace, made sure I notified the subsystem of the change

```
    public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
            {
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
                _workspaces.CollectionChanged += OnWorkspacesChanged;
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_workspaces).CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(MainWindowViewModel_CurrentChanged);
            }
            return _workspaces;
        }
    }

    private void MainWindowViewModel_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentWorkspace = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_workspaces).CurrentItem as WorkspaceViewModel;
        OnPropertyChanged("SaveCommand");
    }

    public WorkspaceViewModel CurrentWorkspace
    {
        get { return _currentWorkspace; }
        set
        {
            _currentWorkspace = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWorkspace");
        }
    }
```

that's it, WPF took care of the rest (ie, enabling, disabling button depending on the validations)!

Again, thanks for your tip Paul.